# How to resend HttpStatus from used REST service from another REST service

Tags: rest, spring-boot, http-status-codes

Problem:

My REST application is using another REST application as it is a "hub" for several other applications.

When a request to this "hub" creates a `HttpClientErrorException` on one of the other REST applications it is managing, I want that `StatusCode` (with message) to be presented to the user of my "hub" and not just the standard internal server 500 error...

How can this be done?

I am using spring-boot 2.1.4 for my "hub" REST application which is sending requests to other REST applications...

Simple failing test spring-boot test case:

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@DisplayName("should use original rest exception")
void shouldUseRestException() {
  when(restTemplateMock.exchange(anyString(), any(), any(), any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class)))
      .thenThrow(new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT, "holy crap!"));

  assertThatExceptionOfType(RestClientException.class).isThrownBy(() -> testRestTemplate.exchange(
      url("/1001"), HttpMethod.GET, null, listOfMyGenericTypes()
  )).withMessage("Http client says: holy crap!");
}
```

My `RestControllerAdvice`:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class HubControllerAdvice {

  @ResponseBody
  @ExceptionHandler
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttClientErrorException(HttpClientErrorException httpClientErrorException) {
    throw new HttpClientErrorException(httpClientErrorException.getStatusCode(), "Http client says: " + httpClientErrorException.getMessage());
  }
}
```

JUnit failure:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expecting message:
 <"Http client says: holy crap!">
but was:
 <"Error while extracting response for type [java.util.List<MyGenericType>] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]">
```

I have a working solution, but this will change the behaviour of the service and I would really want to avoid that. This is to actually return the response entity with status code of the exception as a header in my api... although this works (see below), it requires that users of my hub change their expectations of how it works:

My `RestControllerAdvice`:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class BidragDokumentRestControllerAdvice {

  @ResponseBody
  @ExceptionHandler
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttClientErrorException(HttpClientErrorException httpClientErrorException) {
    return ResponseEntity
        .status(httpClientErrorException.getStatusCode())
        .header(HttpHeaders.WARNING, "Http client says: " + httpClientErrorException.getMessage())
        .build();
  }
}
```

My now working JUnit test:

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@DisplayName("should return empty response with original exception warning")
void shouldReturnEmptyResponseWithOriginalExceptionWarning() {
  when(restTemplateMock.exchange(anyString(), any(), any(), any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class)))
      .thenThrow(new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT, "holy crap!"));

  var errorResponser = testRestTemplate.exchange(
      url("/1001"), HttpMethod.GET, null, listOfMyGenericTypes()
  );
  assertThat(Optional.of(errorResponse)).hasValueSatisfying(responseEntity -> assertAll(
      () -> assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).as("status").isEqualTo(HttpStatus.BANDWIDTH_LIMIT_EXCEEDED),
      () -> assertThat(responseEntity.getBody()).as("body").isNull(),
      () -> {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = errorResponse.getHeaders();

        assertAll(
            () -> assertThat(httpHeaders.get(HttpHeaders.WARNING)).as("warning header").isNotNull(),
            () -> assertThat(httpHeaders.get(HttpHeaders.WARNING)).as("header value").isEqualTo(List.of("Http client says: 509 holy crap!"))
        );
      }
  ));
}
```

Comment: I have tried using a `@RestControllerAdvice` with `@ExceptionHandler`, but this requires to return a `ResponseEntity`. when this entity contains a list of something, spring is unable to create proper json response for this

Comment: From what I understood your hub acts first like an API client because it calls other services which in this case are other REST APIs and on the other hand the hub is acting like a Server because it accepts requests from its own clients. What I would think of first would be how to make these features of the hub as separated as possible. To me it would be a bad design to let low level exceptions like HttpClientError exception escape from the hub service which calls external APIs and let it be handled in the service/controller which responds to clients.

Comment: never mind the exception type... that is not what I am looking for. it is the ability to send the http status... but to indicate what the failure consists of, I would also like the exception message...